# Is doctrees folder required for displaying html docs with Sphinx?

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx

When hosting docs built with Sphinx, the `build` folder has two subdirectories: `doctrees` and `html`. Do I need both folders to display the docs correctly or only the contents of the `html` folder?

If I do need both, do the contents of the `html` folder go into my `public_html` folder and `doctrees` at the same level (outside the publicly accessible portion of my webserver, maintaining the current relative path relationship) or something else?

I can't find the answer in documentation for Sphinx.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `doctrees` (or `.doctrees`) folder contains pickled caches of the source *.rst documents and it is not needed to display the docs correctly. You only need the contents of the `html` folder for that.

See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-d.